# Pronunciation of 'Con' words

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

Is there any rule for the pronunciation of 'Con' words like : 
**Constant**, **Constraint,** **Constitute,** **Constituent** etc. My confusion is with these sounds '**kɒn**' and **'kən'**.

For **Constiuent** it is /**kən**ˈstɪtjʊənt/ but in **Constitute** it's /ˈ**kɒn**stɪtjuːt/.